# Sql Server 2005 Replication to Sql Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible for a Sql Server 2008 R2 Express instance to subscribe to a publication on Sql Server 2005? This is for Merge Replication.

Update:

Please note the Publisher is Sql 2005 and the Subscriber is Sql 2008

Answer:

Looks like answer is No, according to this [paragraph](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx):

"For merge replication, a Subscriber to a merge publication can be any version no later than the Publisher version. For more information about compatibility for earlier versions, see "Compatibility Level for Merge Publications" later in this topic."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express editions can only act as a subscriber in a replication topology. Your scenario should be possible, with a SQL 2005 publisher and a SQL 2008 subscriber, see [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx), as long as the SQL 2005 is at least at SP2:

> SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 can both participate in replication topologies with SQL Server 2008... For SQL Server 2005 the minimum
>   version is Service Pack 2 (SP2).

Comment: Interesting, the article mentions "For merge replication, a Subscriber to a merge publication can be any version no later than the Publisher version. For more information about compatibility for earlier versions, see "Compatibility Level for Merge Publications" later in this topic."

So it seems the answer is No?

Comment: You're right. Thing is I always used Transactional and I wasn't aware of the Merge restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible for both Merge and Transactional Replication. Its all here in the [feature comparison table](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx) under Integration and Interoperability

Comment: Hello - Did you notice the versions are different for the Publisher (Sql 2005) and the Subscriber (Sql 2008)? That is the part I haven't found info about.

Comment: Sorry, I havent noticed that. check this out about Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx